# Help with 3D Axe Model - Issue with Materials

Tags: texturing, materials

I've recently created a 3D model of an axe as one object. I'm using texture maps for the material, but I'm having a problem with the cutting edge part of the axe.

I want the edge between the cutting edge part of the axe and the head of the axe to have a soft transition in between.

When adding two different materials, one for the axe head and one for the cutting edge I get a sharp edge where the materials meet. (See images attached)

If I instead combine these two materials as one and separate them with nodes I’ll get a soft transition but the cutting edge material becomes a straight line instead of a curved line.

I would like to have the cutting edge material curved with a soft transition and was wondering if anyone has any tips or suggestions for how to solve this.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated! I’ve added print screens as well.
Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello what does it give if you use the UV output of the Texture Coordinate? Or please pack your images and share your file?

Comment: Hello. Have you tried using a texture map insted of using generated coordinates to separate both shaders ? Use black and white values dpending on where you want the edge to be

Answer (score 3):

As gorgious commented, a good way out is to use UV coordinates for the transition rather than generated. The UV map for the side of the axe head should be a normal rectangle, so that the straight gradient will bend along the cutting edge. Note that you may want to set up other UV maps for the other textures used in this material. You can manage UV maps in the UV maps panel of the Mesh tab of the Properties editor.